# Get number from array, pass it as a parameter to another page

Tags: php, html

I have a `print` statement in some PHP code:

```
print "<a href='item.php?id='{$row[0]}''><img src='{$row[0]}.jpg'></a>";
```

In `{$row[0]}` is a `int`. When I click on the image I get to a page "restofweburl/item.php?id=" with no number at the end of the URL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your href attr. starts and stops here: `href='item.php?id='`

Answer (score 3):

You end the `href` prematurely with a single quote, after `id=`. Change the line to:

```
print "<a href='item.php?id={$row[0]}'><img src='{$row[0]}.jpg'></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because after the href you have two single quotes. I prefer to use the following syntax:

```
print '<a href="item.php?id='.$row[0].'"><img src="'.$row[0].'".jpg"/></a>';
```

I used single quotes for the print so I can use double quotes for the html attributes (alt/src). This is a prefered method, not a rule, but quite common practice.

As you can see, the color highlighing shows you where the echo ends, a variable gets inserted and the string continues. This makes it easier to spot small mistakes like your double single quote problem.